# Import/Export Build Targets from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.6, release-management

I'm working on an app for iOS, each version we release, we move it to the tags, and continue the work on the trunk of svn.

This app is uploaded as is to many companies to the App Store (with the company logo and information), so each time a company want this app, we make a build target for this company and change the images/logos/info etc.

So, on the latest release, we have many build targets for the companies which is in the tags, and we are planning to release the new version now that is on the trunk.

My question is, how to export/import the build targets from the current release project to the new one? Because it is not logical to repeat this entire process of build targets each time we have to release a new version.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're hoping for.  perhaps a scaled down example of what you're doing would lead us to a better answer.

You may have better luck if you make the location of the branding files a property in the build script and pass the value in at build time.  Rather than calling `ant customer-foo` you could use the same target for all customers and call `ant -Dcustomer.branding.dir=foo`

Comment: Ok, let me put it on simpler way. consider that you have two xcodeprojects, both are similar projects, the first one has 100 build targets (we use each build target for each company), so I want to package the second project for the same 100 companies, can I take the build targets from the first project to the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution was simple, just copied the .xcodeproj file from the old version to the new version, and everything regarding the build settings moved automatically.
Thanks.